# working with char arrays in C

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a method that turns a decimal number into any radix (2-36) and prints the appropriate chars to the screen. The `decimalToSymbol()` method works correctly. The problem I'm having is in the `while` loop I assign `ans[i]` to a `char` and when I try to print it immediately after it is `0`. I have looked online and found this is an OK way to assign the `char` but am not sure what is going wrong.

```
void writeRadixB(int decimalNumber, int radixB)
{
        char ans[80] = ""; 
        int i = 0;
        while(decimalNumber!= 0){ 
                printf("decNum: %d div by rB: %d equals %d\n", decimalNumber, radixB, decimalN
                printf("decNum: %d mod by rB: %d equals %d or char %c\n", decimalNumber, radix
                printf("i: %d\n", i); 
                decimalNumber = decimalNumber/radixB;
                ans[i] = decimalToSymbol(decimalNumber%radixB);
                printf("ans[%d] is %c\n", i, ans[i]);
                i++;
        }   
        printf("(%s) radix %d", ans, radixB);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the values you're passing in? Also, shouldn't you be doing the modulus *before* you divide away the last digit each time?

Comment: I agree with FatalError and also want to note, that your digits will be ordered backwards in the string you create.

Comment: How do you know that the decimalToSymbol method works correctly? Also make sure to null terminate your string. `ans[i]='\0';1 before you print.

Comment: besides you should initialize `char ans[80] = {0};` you should also check `if (radixB != 0) return;`. I'm not quite sure what purpose negative values would have here either. You should also add the (complete) output of your program to enhance the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the line `ans[i] = decimalToSymbol(decimalNumber%radixB);` before the line `decimalNumber = decimalNumber/radixB;`, (to not lose a digit). also, you probably want to reverse the string before printing it.

Comment: This was my problem, thank you. Just have to print the string backwards now

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change decimalNumber until AFTER you've extracted your digit.  That, and your result is backwards.